# Lookup a People/Group column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I know it's one of the limitation to use person column as lookup in another list but is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way using InfoPath forms on a list. It's a little involved. Are you still interested?

The basics involve setting up a secondary data connection to the lookup list and using rules in InfoPath to populate the people picker fields (DisplayName, AccountID, AccountType).

I've also found that you have to hide the people picker controls until there is data in them, otherwise they don't display anything even though there is data in the underlying fields.

I could spend a little time documenting the procedure if you need it.

-Doug

Comment: Could you please provide us more details or a "step-by-step" on how to do it?